# Is it possible to use Class<?> with the new Pattern-Matching switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-17, preview-feature

As part of an investigation into the parameters of a method, I tried the new [Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406). Using a traditional condition, it works perfectly:

```
Method firstMethod = BitSet.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
Parameter firstParameter = firstMethod.getParameters()[0];
if (firstParameter.getType() == Integer.class) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
```

When I tried to refactor it to use a `switch` statement, it did not compile:

```
Method firstMethod = BitSet.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
Parameter firstParameter = firstMethod.getParameters()[0];
switch (firstParameter.getType()) {
    case Integer.class: System.out.println("Integer");
    case int.class: System.out.println("int");
    default: System.out.println("other");
}
```

The error is:

```
 error: incompatible types: Class<Integer> cannot be converted to Class<CAP#1>
        case Integer.class: System.out.println("Integer");
                    ^
 where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
   CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Is this something that can't be done, or is it just a syntax error?

Comment: This does not look like the new syntax, you probably want something like `case Class<Integer> ci : System.out.println("Integer"); break;` and similar for `int`/

Comment: It also doesn't work

Comment: The new switch expression branches the object by its class. `firstParameter.getType()` returns a class object (an instance of `Class`), so that class is always `Class`. So you can't branch in your example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not how switching over types work. You can switch over an object’s actual type and have to specify type names, rather than `Class` literals.

```java
Object o = 42;
switch(o) {
    case Integer i: System.out.println("Integer " + i); break;
    case String s: System.out.println("String " + s); break;
    default: System.out.println("other");
}
```

Note that with pattern matching, there is no fall-through support, so specifying `break` is mandatory. Or you use the new syntax which has no fall-through in the first place

```java
Object o = 42;
switch(o) {
    case Integer i -> System.out.println("Integer " + i);
    case String s -> System.out.println("String " + s);
    default -> System.out.println("other");
}
```

The object returned by `getType()` is always an instance of `java.lang.Class`, so branching by its type makes no sense. This doesn’t mean that comparing the actual values with a `switch` statement or expression was impossible. The comparison can be performed with a guarded pattern:

```java
Method firstMethodWithParam = Arrays.stream(BitSet.class.getDeclaredMethods())
        .filter(m -> m.getParameterCount() > 0)
        .findAny().orElseThrow();
switch(firstMethodWithParam.getParameterTypes()[0]) {
    case Class<?> cl when cl == Integer.class -> System.out.println("Integer");
    case Class<?> cl when cl == int.class -> System.out.println("int");
    case Class<?> cl when cl == String.class -> System.out.println("String");
    case Class<?> cl when cl == long.class -> System.out.println("long");
    case Class<?> cl when BitSet.class.isAssignableFrom(cl)
                                  -> System.out.println("BitSet or subtype");
    default -> System.out.println("other");
}
```

<sup>Note that the JDK 17 preview used `&&` instead of `when`</sup>

but that’s only for completeness. I think it’s obvious that this is no improvement over `if` statements or a map from `Class` to handler.

Comment: Note too there is a difference between `x instanceof C` and `x.getClass() == C.class`; the former includes C and its subtypes; the latter includes exactly C only (which might never be true if C is abstract.)  Type patterns are like `instanceof C`; for final classes like `Integer` it makes no difference, but that's the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @BrianGoetz good point. I expanded the example to show how supporting subtypes would look like.

Comment: For completeness, the reflective spelling of `instanceof` is `Class::isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Well, yes, that’s what I added in the example.

Comment: Isn't this the wrong syntax for the guarded pattern? Instead of `case Class<?> cl && cl == Integer.class` I am expecting `case Class<?> cl when cl == Integer.class`. Did the syntax change or am I missing something?

Comment: @Gili this answer has been written for the preview version. The syntax has changed since then. I’ll update the answer soon.